# Adding a .dll file to a jar

Tags: java, deployment, dll, jar

I have a third party library that comes with .dll files that I need in order to run my java jar file. How can I include them in my jar file when I deploy my application? (I am using JSmooth to create an exe file - if that helps anything)

NOTE: I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files) stackoverflow question, but there's only one answer there, and I don't think it will work for me.

Thanks so much!

Comment: why not ? in other discussions on the topic on stack overflow (i've looked into that question myself as well) web-start has also been offered as a solution, but it basically gets you the same thing - it places the dll in some temp directory and makes it available on the path

Answer (score 3):

this has come up before. the short answer is that you cant - the dll has to be accessible to the underline OS and so cannot be inside the jar.
it can, however, be unpacked from within the jar to somewhere in the PATH before you call loadLobrary ....

look here : [How to make a JAR file that includes DLL files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files)