# Unable to invoke a .exe file inside an executable Jar. How to?

Tags: java, jar

I wanted to invoke a .exe file wrapped inside an executable Jar file. Following is the main class which is supposed to invoke the .exe file.

```
    import java.io.File;

    public class TriggerApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();

            rt.exec("MoreComplexUI.exe");

        }
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            System.out.print(t.getMessage());

        }
    }
    }
```

It does not work. This Jar file contains other supporting files to run the .exe

Answer (score 5):

Its a resource not a physical file.

[You need to extract it somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar) and then execute it with full path

Comment: +1 - Don't be mislead by the title of the linked question.  It applies to EXEs as well as DLLs.