# How to open a Word document in java from our own package?

Tags: java

```
   Desktop desktop = null;
   if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
   {
     desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
   }

   desktop.open(new File("c:\\SRC\\shankar\\a.doc"));
```

Here i don't want to specify the Drive `C:`.

I need my code like

```
desktop.open(new File("\\\SRC\\\shankar\\\a.doc"));
```

Is there is any way?

Comment: hmmm, strange, your code works just fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Make the file available in classpath of the app and then use

`classLoader.getResource("/path/in/class/path")`

it will give you the location of file.

**Note**: the file needs to be out of archieved file. otherwise you need to extract it using code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar)

Comment: java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("/a.doc"); i have used like this... its getting open ... but failed to open when i converted into jar file...

Comment: as you mention above link i found code like FileUtils.openOutputStream  etc... do we need to load in that way..

Comment: yeah it simply copies the file from jar to File system as file

Answer (score 0):

Use *NIX notation:

```
/SRC/shankar/a.doc
```

Comment: Also take a look at [File.listRoots](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29)

Comment: And for completeness: `desktop.open(new File(URI.create("file:///SRC/shankar/a.doc")));`

Answer (score -1):

```
Desktop desktop = null;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
}
String drive = System.getenv("HOMEDRIVE");
desktop.open(new File(drive + "\\SRC\\shankar\\a.doc"));
```

Comment: Hurtle, this depends on an environment variable that is not present by default on non Microsoft Operational Systems. My Ubuntu distro for instance returns `null` for `System.getenv("HOMEDRIVE")`. Since there are available portable solutions I would greatly discourage your answer.

Comment: System.getProperty("user.home")

Comment: yes, but also the string "c:\\SRC\\shankar\\a.doc" that is in the question is not going to work in your Ubuntu distro!!!!!

Comment: That's what we are here to fix right? :D. I mean, if the code was written in a portable way the OP wouldn't have it's initial problem to start with. Environment Variables should be used as last resort, if there are more straightforward ways to achieve the same result in a portable way, why are you suggesting a solution that isn't?