# Where can I place the DLLs that my API jar file depends on?

Tags: dll, jar

I use an API.jar which depends on some DLLs. How can I make my application look for the DLLs that the jar depends on?

Answer (score 0):

pack the dll in jar itself

**Also See**

- [extract-and-load-dll-from-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar)