# How to get the file name of the one being used by a inputStream?

Tags: java

I have a method accepts an InputStream as an argument. How do I find which file is being handled by the passed handler?

For example:

```
public performSomething(InputStream inputStream) {
    System.out.println(FILENAME);
}
```

What should the FILENAME be replaced with such that the name of the file opened by the handler is displayed.

Comment: What do I do? delete this question? I didn't understand that answer though.

Comment: No need to delete it. Just let it be. Users will walk across and close the question as duplicate :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you cannot, because the input stream might not belong to a file. It can be `SocketInputStream`, or `ByteArrayInputStream` for example. The input stream is just an abstraction

Comment: Or it could be standard input.

Comment: say, it is the FileInputStream. Then is there a possibility?

Comment: @ user657592 http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FileInputStream.java You cannot get its name directly, but you can get it's file descriptor - and maybe you can use it somehow to find the name. As a side note- the FileDescriptor is just an `int` - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FileDescriptor.java#FileDescriptor

Comment: Even if the stream belongs to a file, the `FileInputStream` might be wrapped, e.g. in a `BufferedInputStream`. On the other hand, in Oracle’s implementation `SocketInputStream` is a subclass of `FileInputStream` so having a `FileInputStream` does not imply that there is an associated file.

Answer (score 1):

An input stream can be created to read from a file or from any other source of data. Therefore it makes no sense to have a filename attached to an input stream.

Simple Example :

```
InputStream input= assetInfo.openStream();
    File t = new File("");

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(t);

    int read=0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while((read = input.read(bytes))!= -1){
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
```

Look in assetInfo to see if that class exposes that data (you can even look inside the class using reflection). Note that the creator or assetInfo made a design mistake not exposing this information, OR you are trying to make one now.

Comment: I need this for logging purpose. This method may be called from various locations. If I want the file name to be logged, it can't be done. Is that it?

Comment: No it's not that. But it is just an example.

Comment: @Java Curious You are copying the answer from - possible duplicated question's answer, instead you can ask the user to look there directly in comments.

Comment: +1 for "Note that the creator or assetInfo made a design mistake not exposing this information, OR you are trying to make one now."

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are certain you have a `FileInputStream`, you will still be unable to get the underlying file. `FileInputStream` does not retain its `File` argument, but immediately opens the file and retains just the `FileDescriptor`, a wrapper around the native `int` handle to the OS resource.

As of OpenJDK version 7, Update 40, a `String path` variable has been introduced, so with some luck you may try to *reflectively* get it.

Of course, this can be nothing more than heurstics. There is no official way through the public API.

Comment: So, in short, there is no fail-proof way I can get the file name?

Comment: No, unfortunately there isn't.