# FileUtils.listFiles() on resources directory

Tags: java, resources, apache-commons-io

In my project I have a `resources` directory with a `my_directory` inside. `my_directory` contains text files.

I want to loop this directory with:

```
URL resource = Resources.class.getResource("/my_directory");
File directory = new File(resource.getPath());
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(directory, new String[]{"txt"}, true);
```

`files` collection contains all `.txt` files.

It works well if I run this project in debugger. However if I build project to `jar` file, it gives an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
```

`directory` file path is:

```
/home/hsz/.../lib/my_project.jar!/my_directory
```

How can I use Apache's `FileUtils` on resources directory ?

Comment: Classpath entries/resources are not necessarily files. You shouldn't be reading them as files.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So how can I retrieve `/my_directory` content without knowing, what's inside ?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question to me, have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012819/how-can-i-get-a-resource-folder-from-inside-my-jar-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the files / directories are bundled inside a .jar file, they are no longer be treated as `File` objects. They can be read by acquiring their inputstream like

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("my_directory/file");
```

I would suggest you to keep the folder with files in the filesystem and make the operations you want to perform. Is there any reason, you want to bundle them into a jar prior to these manipulation.

As per the answer in the below question, *In Java 7, you can create a FileSystem from the JAR (zip) file, and then use NIO's directory walking and filtering mechanisms to search through it. This would make it easier to write code that handles JARs and "exploded" directories*. You can try that!

Comment: I cannot provide files outside of the jar file - it's a plugin file.
Is it possible to list files in `my_directory/` as a resource file somehow ?

Comment: Please check this one - I think you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = Resources.class.getResource("/my_directory");
URI uri = url.toURI();
if (uri.getScheme().equals("jar")) {
    // parse JAR file name
    String jarPath = uri.toString().replaceFirst("jar:file:", "").replaceFirst("!.*$", "");
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(URLDecoder.decode(jarPath, "UTF-8"));

    // loop through the entries in the JAR looking for ones in the proper directory
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
    while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = entries.nextElement().getName();
        if (name.startsWith(rootDirResource.substring(1))) // or a more complex check for *.txt files
            System.out.println("found: " + name);
    }

    jar.close();
}
```