# How to list all files from the resources directory

Tags: java

Source is a Java Maven project.

Java **resources** directory contains subdirectories that contain configuration files. Config files can be added and removed as a maintenance process. Names of files not suppose to be known.

How I can get a list of all files in a mentioned project "resources" directory?

There is a solution using Spring framework class `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`, however this class requires Apache Commons Logging and when dependency added the project is getting set to java 1.7 source from 1.8 that breaks existing code compatibility.

Does java have a class that can list files of a mentioned folder, or java was never need it?

Update:
Was able to resolve the issue with this solution (else condition //Run with IDE)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20073154/323128

*path* is a folder name inside "resources" directory.

Comment: @Burkhard Not a duplicate to the referred question.

Comment: Thank you for closing without help ignorant community members! You could help at least with a right link if you took time to read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JarFile class to interrogate the contents of JARs programmatically: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html.

Some examples: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.util.jar.JarFile

You can also use jar.exe from the JDK itself to interrogate JAR files. This command will show everything under the resources level from the root...

```
jar tf YourApplication.jar resources
```

The Guava ClassPath class may also be worth looking at: (https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.java).

Comment: Jar's resource directory. Thank you for links.

Comment: Updated my answer to give an additional way of doing it via jar.exe.

Comment: Your hints brought me to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012819/how-can-i-get-a-resource-folder-from-inside-my-jar-file that resolved my question. Thanks for the help and I take it as an answer.