# Spring Boot 1.4.1 runnable jar javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have a Spring Boot 1.4.1 application and when we create runnable jar and try to run it, we get following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxEntityManager' defined in class path resource [xxx/web/config/XxxConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.Persistenc
eException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at xxx.App.main(App.java:48) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [NES-Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [NES-Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [NES-Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [NES-Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:605) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:445) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:426) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:325) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:602) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

We also found this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6635, but according to it, this should be fixed in Spring Boot 1.4.1

NOTE: we don't have annotations in our model classes, we use hbm.xml files for mapping. But, we use Spring Data JPA repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on directions I read here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6983#issuecomment-249981782) I managed to create workaround this problem by doing following:

1. I created *META-INF/orm.xml* file and put it in src/main/resources folder. File's contents can be found at this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/resources/META-INF/orm.xml (you don't actually need *persistence-unit-metadata*, *named-query* and *entity* tags, just an empty XML with root *entity-mappings* tag is enough).
2. When configuring *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* bean, I need to call *setPersistenceUnitRootLocation* method and set location to **classpath:META-INF/orm.xml**

This workaround solves mine problem when running fat jar. However, by implementing this workaround I created another problem - I was unable to run an app from IDE, so I had to implement some sort of conditional setting of persistence unit's root location, based on some indicator whether I'm running a jar or from IDE.

Comment: I learned how to detect fat jar mode here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20073154/43392

Answer (score 0):

You're probably affected by [this regression](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6983). There's a workaround provided in the issue. Please give that a try and wait for  `1.4.2.RELEASE`. Sorry :(

Comment: Stephane, I uploaded sample project in a comment to that issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error building the jar with maven-jar-plugin but building the jar like following works properly:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>
```