# Using Thymeleaf to dynamically generate link tags for CSS files in folder

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

Is it possible to have Thymeleaf dynamically generate a list of CSS `<link>` tags for all CSS files in a folder?

For example, if I have a folder:

`src/main/resource/static/css`

with `aaa.css` and `bbb.css`, how could I have Thymeleaf create a `<link>` tag for each file it finds in the folder (without having to specify the name of each file)?

The names of the css files change frequently, and we don't want to have to update the Thymeleaf template every time.

Comment: While you could probably do this, I don't think Thymeleaf is the right tool for this... Maybe investigate adding a process to your build that combines all the css into single css file when you build the application, and just link to that one file?

Comment: Listing resources is tricky. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012819/how-can-i-get-a-resource-folder-from-inside-my-jar-file/20073154 for a discussion.