# How to execute script from JAR file?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a maven project, in which, I am trying to execute a script (written in R). I put this script file in the source code directory as well. I found this script is not executed at all. However, when I move this script outside the jar file, it does execute ! Can anyone tell me why, and give me some solutions to put the script inside the jar while ensure its execution?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do the following:

- Get InputStream for the file with ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()
- Write this InputStream to tmp dir
- Execute it with Runtime.getRuntime().execute(..)

Comment: @carlspring yes, i do agree, but it will be better to give a little bit code for step 2. I don't know how to create the temporary file, where the temporary locates, and delete it on exit ? Thanks ~

Comment: @EnsomHodder To create use something like this:     File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix")

Comment: @EnsomHodder To delete use File.deleteOnExit();

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov so after creating the temp file, I create an outputstream to write the script file into this newly created tmp file, and then call it ?

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov Excuse me, I am trying your method however i cannot manage to it. Firstly, i get the **inputstream** from the given file name "./src/main/resources/aaa.R" (script to execute) ; secondly, I create a temp file, and from which I create a **FileOutputStream** to write the script in. However it will throws a NullPointerException when my program tries to read bytes array from the inputstream obtained by **getResourcesAsStream**. Could you help me survive from it ? I am very grateful for your help !

Comment: @EnsomHodder 1. You should make sure that you copied aaa.R to the compiler output dir. 2. You should call getResourceAsStream("/resources/aaa.R") not the full path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13447/discussion-between-ensom-hodder-and-konstantin-solomatov)

Answer (score 1):

File inside jar is no longer a file, So to execute it you first need to [extract it somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar) and then execute it from external extracted file path

Comment: You mean extract the whole jar file or only the script file to be executed? And could you please tell me how to extract one single file from jar ?

Comment: Just extract the required file from jar, see the link for more details from answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. after the execution of the script, I have to remove the extracted files. Seems that it's not very clean ~ but most of all, it works

Comment: By the way. I don't know where the class ***ACWrapper*** comes from? Could you explain it ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extract the script from the jar file:

```
jar -xvf my.jar com/foo/my.script.sh
```

Comment: so you mean it's better to execute this command from the Java program, and then execute the second command (extracted file) ? it seems it's quite simple and doesn't not any external library support ~