# How to include the script file in the jar

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu

I want to execute a script file from Java , so i have  used the following lines of code to execute the script file.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();          

Process proc = rt.exec("/home/akshay/NetBeansProjects/testapplication/src/test_script");
```

But runtime.execute("path/to/file/") requires String as parameters which is path to the file , but i need to include the script file in the Jar.

So please help to how to include a script file inside the jar and also what parameters should i provide in the runtime.execute("please specify what parameters should i supply when i copy and paste the script files in the current pacakge")

Comment: You can not execute a script that resides inside a JAR file. You have to extract it and the execute it.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339979/how-to-execute-script-from-jar-file, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603807/executing-a-shell-script-inside-a-jar-file-how-to-extract for Linux scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runtime.exec` requires a command name that can be interpreted by the operating system, and neither Windows, Linux or Mac OSX are capable of executing a command directly out of a JAR file (or a ZIP file or a TAR file, or ...)

You will need to extract the script file from your JAR file into the file system and then run the script from the file.

---

<sup>In theory, you could get the OS to mount the JAR file as a filesystem.  However, this is liable to not work due to issues with file locking ... assuming that the JAR file is also on your application's classpath.</sup>