# Cannot set file to writable in Java Applet

Tags: java, file, dll, applet

I'm trying to load a dll file from a jar to work with the applet with this fix:

[Extract and load DLL from JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar)

I create the file, set it writable and executable, but when I check it with canWrite()/canExecute()
it returns false. The applet is signed.

The code:

```
private static void loadLib() {
URL res = SystemActivityNotifications.class.getResource("/sys-native
    /sysactivitynotifications.dll");
InputStream in = res.openStream();
File dll = new File(path + "sysactivitynotifications.dll");
dll.setExecutable(true);
dll.setWritable(true);
logger.info(dll.canWrite() + " " + dll.canExecute());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dll);
byte[] array = new byte[1024];
try {
    for(int i = in.read(array); i != 1; i=in.read(array)) {
        fos.write(array, 0, i);
    }
} catch (IOException e) { logger.info("Cannot write to file: " + e.getMessage()); }
fos.close();
in.close();
System.load(dll.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

The file is created properly, but it throws an exception while trying to write to it.

edit: it writes to the file the second time I run the applet, but if I delete the file and run again the first iteration doesn't work.

Forgot to mention: all the code above is from a catch block after System.load.library(dll); throws the exception.

```
try
    {
        System.loadLibrary("sysactivitynotifications");

        ptr = allocAndInit();
        if (ptr == -1)
            ptr = 0;
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        if (t instanceof ThreadDeath)
            throw (ThreadDeath) t;
        else {
           loadLib();
        }
    }
```

Edit: it throws me this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Answer (score 1):

> ..trying to load a dll file from a jar to work with the applet..

For deploying Java applets, the best option is usually to launch the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, Java-FX, AWT, SWT..) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of **natives** & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or locale, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Place the natives in the root of a (signed) Jar and put a reference to that Jar in the launch file and they will be placed on the class-path of the app.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but we are not using JWS, and the dll downloads & executes correctly but only in the second run.

Comment: @DimaO were you able to figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Yes, but I don't remember exactly, I changed all the downloading code, and the DLLs are changed as well...if you have the same problem you could check what process locking the DLL, maybe download it to a different folder that's in java path