# Include music in .jar with netbeans

Tags: java, file, netbeans, jar

I know this question has been asked before, but I couldn't actually understand the solution to the problem, that's why I'm posting my code specifically!

When I run the program from netbeans the music is just fine. However, when I run it from the jar file, the program is executed smoothly, but without music.

I used this code to play music: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml

And I call the function like this in GUI class:

```
musicPlayer = new AePlayWave("src/songs/Full_Despicable_Me_Theme_Song_-_Pharrell_Williams.wav");
        musicPlayer.start();
```

(as you can see I have a package called "songs", which contains the song)

Hope you can help!

Comment: have a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java

Comment: Don't include "src" in the path, it won't exist once the program is built. You may need to use Class#getResource or Class#getRescourceAsStream depending of the API you are using

Answer (score 0):

Constructor of [`AePlayWave`](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs56/examples/sound/clipsInJar/javadoc/edu/ucsb/cs56/pconrad/examples/sound/clipsInJar/AePlayWave.html#AePlayWave%28java.lang.String%29) takes file path as parameter, when you have your music file inside jar file, it is no longer a `File`

You can [read that file and write it out to some temp directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar) on the bootstrap of your program and read it as `File` from that location