# Using jogl in runnable jar, manual loading of dll

Tags: java, dll, jogl, executable-jar

I'm using the jogl library to make nice 3D plots in my program. To use it in a runnable jar, I use the well-known trick to copy the dll out of it and putting it in a temporary location (for details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files), also for the **loadLib** function mentioned below )

The problem is that I keep getting Unsatisfied link errors:

```
static {
        mylogger().info("Loading jogl DLL");

        // we need to put both DLLs to temp dir
        String path = "MYAPP_" + new Date().getTime();
        try {
            loadLib(path, "gluegen-rt");
            loadLib(path, "jogl");
            loadLib(path, "jogl_cg");
            loadLib(path, "jogl_awt");
            libraryLoaded = true;
        } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            mylogger().error("Cannot load JOGL libraries: "+e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

So, is there something wrong with the order of the libraries included? How can I find out what's the cause of the unsatisfied link error?

Comment: Do you know which library is missing? Did you check for the correct path?

Comment: @Thomas: No, it doesn't give me any information what library is missing.

Comment: What's the message of the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`? Did you put an individual try-catch block around each `loadLib()` call in order to see where exactly it is thrown (or debug somehow)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the JogAmp "Fat-Jar" layout then JOGL and Gluegen will find and load the native library from inside your runnable jar.

use the following layout inside your jar:

```
 /natives/<os.and.arch>/libLala1.so
 /natives/<os.and.arch>/libLala2.so
```

https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Custom_Bundling