# 7Zip-JBinding UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've looked through a number of the UnsatisfiedLinkError threads on here and nothing seems to quite fit my problem.

I am trying to get this api working: [7ZipBind](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/index.html)

However I am having an issue, and cant get the thing to work. I am running some of its example code from the commandline like so:

> C:>java -classpath
>   "/sevenzipTest.jar;/sevenzipjbinding-AllWindows.jar;\sevenzipjbinding.jar"
>   com.poc.sevenzip.SevenZipSimple c:\archive\test.zip

However when I try to run it I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\SevenZipJBinding-9640553\lib7-Zip-JBinding.dll: Can't
find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZip.initSevenZipFromPlatformJARIntern(SevenZip.java:428)
        at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZip.initSevenZipFromPlatformJAR(SevenZip.java:235)
        at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZip.ensureLibraryIsInitialized(SevenZip.java:578)
        at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZip.openInArchive(SevenZip.java:567)
        at com.poc.sevenzip.SevenZipSimple.runZip(SevenZipSimple.java:25)
        at com.poc.sevenzip.SevenZipSimple.main(SevenZipSimple.java:64
```

What I am confused about, is why it says it cant locate the libraries (dll files), when the libraries are stored within the `<file_path>/sevenzipjbinding-AllWindows.jar` file... I am obviously not doing something correct here, and was hoping some1 can give me some pointers.

Cheers

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to load the dll directly from the jar-archive...you need to extract them first.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug fix was released. Please, use version 1.06rc or above.

Download URL:

- [All versions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzipjbind/files/7-Zip-JBinding/)
- [4.65-1.06rc-extr-only](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzipjbind/files/7-Zip-JBinding/4.65-1.06rc-extr-only/)

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions are for Windows x86 and 7 Zip JBinding version 4.65-1.05 RC.  Download the following DLLs.

- [libstdc++-6.dll](http://code.google.com/p/wtfu/downloads/detail?name=libstdc%2B%2B-6.dll&can=2&q=)
- [libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll](http://pt.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_openmarias/downloads/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll/)
- [gpsvc.dll](http://www.dllme.com/dll/download/3948/gpsvc.dll)
- [sysntfy.dll](http://www.dllme.com/dll/download/4568/sysntfy.dll)

Add the DLLs into the `Windows-x86` directory in `sevenzipjbinding-AllPlatforms.jar`.  Then append the following lines to `sevenzipjbinding-lib.properties` in the `Windows-x86` directory in the jar.

```
sevenzipjbinding.libname.3=gpsvc.dll
sevenzipjbinding.libname.4=libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
sevenzipjbinding.libname.5=libstdc++-6.dll
sevenzipjbinding.libname.6=sysntfy.dll
```

Instead of modifying the jar file, one could put the DLLs in the PATH (not classpath).

In order to figure this out, I extracted `lib7-Zip-JBinding.dll` from [sevenzipjbinding-AllPlatforms.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzipjbind/files/7-Zip-JBinding/4.65-1.05rc-extr-only/sevenzipjbinding-4.65-1.05-rc-extr-only-AllPlatforms.zip/download).  I then opened the file in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/depends22_x86.zip).