# Java3D through SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

I have a problem that is somewhat similar to this post.

[How do I dynamically load the Java3D library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838393/how-do-i-dynamically-load-the-java3d-library)

I have a project where I can install Java3D on my system and then use the Java3D libraries in my project. But when I upload it to the SVN, and get it from another computer, it doesn't work.

I tried making a lib folder in the project and adding the .jar files from the lib folder in the properties. But this still doesn't work.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Did you install it on the other computer?

Comment: Doesn't help the specific problem, but consider using maven.
You should not be storing binaries in source control.
Maven will allow you to store your library configuration in source and allow users to let maven download them into their project.

Answer (score 0):

SVN is thinking that your .jar files are text files and processing them as usual. So, if the data is moved between platforms it will be corrupted, because SVN will "fix" the end of line code.

This question has information on how to solve it: [How do I tell Subversion to treat a file as a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73797/how-do-i-tell-subversion-to-treat-a-file-as-a-binary-file)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the JARs, Java3D loads a set of native libraries.  Did you include these in your project and SVN repository?

Also, keep in mind, the native libraries are platform-specific.  If you want your program to run on all Java3D-supported platforms, you can include all the native libs and unpack/load the ones you need dynamically.