# adding path to java build

Tags: java, rxtx, unsatisfiedlinkerror

In my project I have an rxtx library that I use to manage Serial comms. When I run the application in netbeans ide I have no problems. I have put the rxtx files in my java folders and added the path in the project libraries.
The problems start when I build the jar file for the project. It creates the jar file and adds the folder for costum libraries at /lib folder. However I am not able to run the jar file by double clicking on it. When I run it from command line I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

What should I do in order for the program be able to find the rxtx library in the /lib folder?

Comment: What does your command line command look like?

Comment: Finally found a solution to this myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596406/java-rxtx-and-packaging/16716867#16716867
the problem is that it does not take the dll file. so you need to manually put it in the /dist folder. Hope this helps to ppl :)

Answer (score 0):

You must either:

1. Provide the classpath containing your /lib when you run java from the command line. Use the -cp option to do this.
2. Properly create an executable jar that bundles your /lib. I use maven and this plugin to create that: https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the program from the command line, you will need to specify the `java.library.path` to make sure that your native libraries are accessible by the JVM.

Without knowing how you actually run your program, I am going to take a guess at what the command *should* look something like:

```
java -cp yourjar.jar -Djava.library.path=/yourProjectPath/lib gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the required libraries into the jar file (when you don't want to use command line).  Checkout [this](http://arunasujith.blogspot.nl/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html) site to make this happen at netbeans.