# How to pack a library in a jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, native

I am new to working with any native library and this question might seem stupid so please bear with me.

I downloaded LTI-CIVIL to capture video input from webcam. It requires me to create a library in Eclipse and point out the location of the native files.

Assuming the native dlls are located at `E:\files\lti-civil\src\native\ms(x86)`, I want to add these along with the jar file and make a standalone application that I can send to my friends.

Currently, I can run the program from Eclipse itself as it points to `E:\blah_blah` but it may not be the case on other person's computer

Now, how do I pack these so that I can make a stand alone application ? do I create a folder in src of Eclipse and add the folder there or what ?

Comment: Make sure you use relative references. Then: rightclick the project -> export -> java -> jar file... there you can select what to export

Comment: @Heuster Ok, so add the things to src folder and use relative referencing ? If you elaborate, I will accept this as an answer :)

Comment: Apparently, you cannot do this with dll's, as explained by Joni. I would accept his answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLLs cannot be packed in a jar file because Java cannot load DLLs from an archive file on Windows. One possibility is to distribute something that includes the Java program (as a .jar) and the DLLs separately, and both are extracted on installation.

Popular choices are: a ZIP file the user would have to extract manually, a self-extracting ZIP file, or a "setup" program generated for example by [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Another possibility is to pack the DLL in the .jar file and have the application extract it on startup, for example into a temporary directory.

Once the DLL is on the file system you can load it with `System.load` or `System.loadLibrary`.

Comment: JAR files don't have to be compressed though. Or are you saying Windows cannot read DLL's from any archive file?

Comment: Alternatively, you can pack the DLL/s in the jar file, and have the application automatically extract the appropriate DLLs before running. OSGi does this.

Comment: Yes, @Perception, that's what I mean. My use of "compressed file" can be misleading, will edit.

Comment: Thanks @AndyThomas-Cramer, will edit to mention that possibility.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files). As it covers what you are trying to do.

Just to cover what that answers says to do is package up the .dlls inside a .jar. Include that .jar inside your project. Before you run you extract them to a temp folder and tell your program to use that location.

To make a self contained JAR from Eclipse do the following steps.

[image: Step 1]

Right click on your project and select Export

[image: Step 2]

Under Java select Runnable JAR File

[image: Step 3]

Select extract required libraries into generated JAR

This would allow you to send a single stand alone application to send to who you like.

Comment: Says it can't find module.