# Where to put my .dll to be accessed in my jar

Tags: java, dll

I have a java application that need to load a certain dll. i have putted my .dll in the project it run well from eclipse but when i export my project to runnable jar, i cannot run the jar and an exeption is 
unsatisfiedlinkerror, no dllname in java.library.path
i need the jar to have the dll inside and have a full runnable jar without the need to make any configuration to the build path of each customer.

Comment: See ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files)*** post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just package it anywhere in the jar. One thing you have to keep in mind though - before you can use the DLLs you need to actually extract these from the JAR and dump these on the hard disk somewhere otherwise you won't be able to load these

[How to make a JAR file that includes DLL files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files)

Comment: so there no way to the dll to be accessed in my jar as question said and have to extract in on the hard  drive and access it. thank @woliveirajr