# Export Runnable Jar with DLL

Tags: java

I have a program that has a dll and resource files. I tried to export runnable jar, but i gives an error dll not found.

How can i export it ?

I can run without error in eclipse but i could not export the project.

I call the native lib below :

```
public class DLL_Functions {
    public interface DLL extends Library {
        DLL INSTANCE = (DLL) Native.loadLibrary("ErgoPointer_64_Bit_DLL", DLL.class);
        int LSX_CreateLSID(IntByReference ILSID);
        int LSX_ConnectSimple(int ILSID, int lAnInterfaceType, String pcAComName, int lABaudRate, boolean bAShowProt);
        int LSX_SetShowProt (int ILSID, boolean bShowProt);
        int LSX_Disconnect(int ILSID);
        int LSX_GetPos(int ILSID, DoubleByReference pdX, DoubleByReference pdY, DoubleByReference pdZ, DoubleByReference pdA);
        int LSX_SetPos(int ILSID, double dX, double dY, double dZ, double dA);
        int LSX_GetKey(int ILSID, IntByReference key1, IntByReference key2, IntByReference key3, IntByReference key4);
    } 
}
```

Also i have image and settings files too.

Comment: So after exporting, where is the DLL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a JAR file that includes DLL files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-includes-dll-files)