# which jar has ACWrapper class

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am looking at post
[How to make a JAR file that includes DLL files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-includes-dll-files#)

May be my question will silly one? Searched on google and maven.But unable to get jar file having ACWrapper class.
**Can someone help me to get above code into working condition?**

Answer (score 0):

Found solution on github code posted by shout-poor
[ACWrapper Class Link](https://github.com/shout-poor/Smallcodes/blob/master/ACWrapper.java)