# How to refer a folder inside the jar

Tags: java, dll

I have a Java file which refers to a *.dll* to perform Windows authentication.

In my Java code, I used `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` to get the PATH, and then I manually appended the PATH of the DLL. It works fine.

But I dont want the DLL to sit in some folder outside. So I moved the DLL file inside a Jar file which contains my Java-class file.
I am not sure how to refer to the location of the folder inside my jar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths?

`<folder name>/<filename>.dll`

Comment: There are no folders inside jars; this is a common problem for people new to Java. If you _have_ to have something as a file (like you would for a DLL), you have to copy it into a file from the jar resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a JAR file that includes DLL files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-includes-dll-files)

Comment: You can't do this. The operating system requires the DLL to be in its file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getClass().getResource()` for that!

I recommend to first create a folder in your project dedicated to resources.

Then place your `.dll` file in there.

Then to refer to it, type something like this:

```
URL toDLL = getClass().getResource("Resources/someDLL.dll");
```

Note: This won't work in static methods like in the `main()` method of the Main class, so for that, type `Main.class.getResource()` instead.

Here it is in action using IntelliJ:

[image]